# How to Load If Statement After Form Loads

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how I can make an If statement run right after my Form3 loads. I've been searching the web for almost an hour now and I can't seem to find any information on how to do it.

If you need specifics on what I'm trying to do, it's an If statement for a conditional PictureBox1 image load. The Public variable is initially set in Form2,

```
Public Class Form2

    Public specialist As String = "None"

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  Button2.Click
        specialist = "Battery: War Machine"
        My.Forms.Form3.Show()
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  Button3.Click
        specialist = "Battery: Kinetic Armor"
        My.Forms.Form3.Show()
        Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then in Form3, I want to know how to run this if statement.

```
Public Class Form3
    Public specialist As String = (Form2.specialist)
    If specialist = "Battery: War Machine" Then
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.BatteryLobby3
    Else
        PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Nope
    End If
End Class
```

But I want it to run right when Form3 starts, without having to click a button or anything.

Comment: You want the Form_Initialize event. http://www.homeandlearn.org/the_form_initialize_event.html

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, there is no such event in VB.NET. The link you provided is for VBA.

Comment: Sorry for some reason I thought this was VBA

Comment: The load event should change your PictureBox. But you should declare in a module the global variable Specialist. then, in the form_close event clean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Load` event of a form is raised immediately before the form is displayed for the first time.  The `Shown` event is raised immediately after the form is displayed for the first time.

Comment: Would you please explain to me how to use these two events exactly? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need an explanation.  They are events like any other.  If you know how to "use" the `Click` event of a `Button` then you know all you need to know.

Comment: Ok, so I just tried using the Show command, as I found a page on Form.Shown, but now when I try the program, I only get the error BC30203, Identifier expected. I looked at the error help and it seems to me that I both have spelled all elements correctly, and all attributes have been mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: I used Private Sub Form3_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _ Handles Form3.Shown before my If statement.

Comment: Never find, I figured out how to solve my problem. I had to replace Form3.Shown with Me.Shown. Thank you for your time!

Comment: You should always let the IDE create the event handler for you.  Those drop-downs at the top of the code window are there for good reason.